# How to alter a DOM Element during MouseUp Event without Disrupting Double-Click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to remove a CSS class name from the targeted DOM Element during a `mouseup` event handler, but doing so seems to prevent the double-click event from firing. I guess this is due to the fact that I'm altering the DOM element to which the double-click is attached to and JavaScript is cancelling the event queue because the element changed. The only thing I've come up with so far is to put the removal of the CSS class in a timeout of 300 ms or so...

Here's some rough code. jQuery is just for convenience.

```
var myElm = $(someElm);
    myElm
      .mouseup(function(e) { $(this).removeClass("abc"); })
      .dblclick(function (e) { alert ('hi!'); });
```

It'll never say hi!.

Anybody got an elegant solution for this?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/MK8hy/

Comment: @Felix it doesn't work for me ... which browser are you using?

Comment: @wong2: Ok just to clarify: The OP wants to have both handlers called during double click right? I'm using Chrome 9 on Mac OS X. Works also in Firefox 3.6.13 (Mac).

Comment: @felix @wong2 - works for me, Safari 5.0.3 Mac

Comment: @felix Oh, it works for me too..I just had some misunderstanding. I test it in Chrome, Firefox, IE8 on Windows

Comment: Could it be that you are doing something in the `mouseup` handler which throws an error the second time the handler is called? During a double click, the `mouseup` handler gets called twice. Or are you really only removing the class? You said you use jQuery for convenience, do you use plain JavaScript in your orignal code? If so, you should post this.

Comment: Yes. You are all correct. It is working fine... I should have put together a smaller test case before posting. As it does nine out of ten times, it was the particulars of my case that were causing the double-click to fail. When I pulled all the code to a small test case, the mistake became apparent.

Answer (score 1):

Probably removing the class "abc" you change the size or visibility of an object that becomes unclickable so the event wont be triggered. Try to store this properties (like width, height, visibility) in another class which you wont remove.

Even this works for me just fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            border: solid 1px black;
            background-color: Green;
        }
        .style2
        {
            background-color: Red;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var myElm = $('.style2');
            myElm
              .mouseup(function (e) { $(this).removeClass("style2"); })
              .dblclick(function (e) { alert('hi!'); });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="style1 style2" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In my case, the abc was just a market class added by a jQuery plugin... but yes, if I was correct in my original thinking that it was causing the DOM element to re-layout, your answer might have been the correct way to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I think either of these approaches will work for you:

```
  .mouseup(function(e) { 
    $(this).removeClass("abc"); 
    e.stopPropagation();  
  })
```

and

```
  .mouseup(function() { 
    $(this).removeClass("abc"); 
    return false;
  })
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what the OP *not* wants. He is experiencing the same effect as using `stopPropagation` but he does not want that.

Comment: But he **wants** the "dblclick" handler to run ... your solution guarantees that it won't.

Comment: It still runs for me.  I'm just stopping the mouseup event from propagating.

Comment: True, this probably works because `mouseup` and  `dblclick` are different events. But why stopping it then if it has the same effect as not stopping it?